Adding prismatic joint in the gazebo cause moles to behave erratically in gazebo
I've designed a robot model in Fusion 360, resembling TARS from the movie Interstellar. I exported the model into a URDF package for ROS 2 using a Fusion 360 plugin. The model loads perfectly in Gazebo, but the problem starts when I try to make the robot move.
The robot's movement is supposed to simulate TARS: first, a side arm moves up, then rotates, and finally falls forward. The issue arises when the robot begins to fall forward—midway through the motion, the robot starts behaving erratically, flying away or moving uncontrollably.
To isolate the problem, I removed all the legs and joints, leaving only the base link. When I manually rotate the base link forward in Gazebo, the motion is smooth and fine. However, when I add just a single prismatic joint (which is connected to the base link to move up and down), the erratic behavior returns when the robot falls forward—once again, it flies away uncontrollably.
I've tried adjusting various parameters like effort, velocity, damping, etc., but the issue persists.
Here’s a link to a video showing the problem: https://youtu.be/gZSS4toRDJE.
And here’s the link to my package: https://github.com/Ishansehgal/Tars.git. The package in question is tars_robot_description.
